# UISwitch Programmatic Constraints for iPhone4, 5, & 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout, uiswitch

Is there a way to program constraints for a UISwitch such that the position specified in `CGRectMake(155, 342.5, 0, 0)` is maintained throughout iPhone4, iPhone5, & iPhone6. Source code:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *autoPlaySwitch;
        ...

_autoPlaySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(155, 342.5, 0, 0)];
[_autoPlaySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(autoPlay:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.view addSubview:_autoPlaySwitch];

- (void)autoPlay:(id)sender
{                    
    if([sender isOn])
         NSLog(@"Switch is ON");
    else
         NSLog(@"Switch is OFF");
}
```

Comment: If the element is at a fixed position, you don't need constraints. Do you really want to make the width and height = 0?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! UISwitch is of a standardized size so that adding values for width or height in `GCRectMake` evaluate to `nil`. Do you know if we can drop the zeros at the end?  `GCRectMake`'s position may be fixed but UISwitch's relation to its surrounding UI elements is not. I can upload screenshots.

Comment: You can use top constraint and leading constraint?

Comment: @kientux Do you know if there is a way to make these constraints programmatically?

Comment: I just suggest that, if there's a screenshot about what you want to do, it may help for more detail.